# Sharing MTLTexture

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I have a MTLTexture of a UIImage.I am drawing the MTLTexture. I zoom the MTL Texture. I made some changes in the zoomed MTLTexture. I want to make the changes to the original(not Zoomed) MTLTexture. Any way to achieve that

Comment: You need to explain better. **How** have you "zoomed" the texture? Be specific. Show code. What does "made some changes" mean, specifically? How did you do that?

Comment: I zoomed using transformation Matrix. The changes I made is drawn a triangle in the zoomed drawable. Thanks